# how to access the labels using tags in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am implementing an iphone application.Which is a UItableview.It has two sections.Three labels are added to all the cells in section-I.I have given tags 1,2,3 for those 3 labels when adding to the cells.Now I want to get the values from label3 from all the cells from section-I and I would like to add all the float values and display the total in another label which is in section-II.I read that I should give different tags for different cell's label3(label with tag-3).How is it possible please guide me.I have float values in the label3.I wanna add all the values and present the result in section-II.Please help me with some reference.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
NSString* curItem = [self.finalItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString* curQuantity = [self.finalPrices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString* priceStr = [self fetchDishRecordswithpredicate:curItem];
NSMutableString* priceValStr = [NSMutableString stringWithString:priceStr];
[priceValStr replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1) withString:@""];
float totalPrice = [curQuantity floatValue]*[priceValStr floatValue];
UILabel *lblTemp1 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
UILabel *lblTemp2 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
UILabel *lblTemp3 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
switch (indexPath.section) {
    case 0: {
    lblTemp1.text = curItem;
    lblTemp2.text = curQuantity;
    lblTemp3.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$ %0.2f", price];
    } break;
    case 1: {
        lblTemp1.text = @"Your Total:";
        lblTemp3.text = @"How can I get Total here";
    } break;
 }
return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It should never be necessary to get the value of a label, whether it's part of a table cell or some other kind of view. The user can't modify a label -- they're for display only. That means that the only way that a label can get a given value is for your program to set that value, and that in turn means that you've already got the data you need somewhere. That holds true for any kind of view other than controls that are used for getting input from the user.

The fact that you're looking to get values from labels probably means that you're using your views to store data, which is not a good practice. Views display data, but that data should be stored elsewhere in the program, typically in a data model (assuming you're following the MVC paradigm).

All that said, you can get the cell for a given row from your table using its `-cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. From there, you can access the cells subviews using the usual `-viewWithTag:` method. You definitely don't need a unique set of tags for each cell -- you just need to get the cell for the row that you're interested in. However, keep in mind that a table usually only keeps the cells that are visible around; if you ask it for the cell for a row that's not visible, it'll probably have to create that cell, which in turn will involve asking the table's delegate (your own code!) for the cell. That's a pretty expensive way to ask yourself for data that you already have! ;-)

Comment: I guess You are talking About Dao connected to a database in a MVC paradigm and sure ..you might not know what he implemented internally...he certainly has to display data and tableview may contain lable..and labels might change according to datasource ...so y was i voted dwn?

Comment: @roronoazorro I didn't downvote, but perhaps it was for the lack of explanation? Also, as I wrote above, the data gets placed into the labels in the first place via the app's code, so it shouldn't be necessary to ask the table for it... if you need to, ask your data source instead.